# conflicts with POST and scripts

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I have a HTML form that submits to a php page.
I would like to use Jquery Mobile on my pages as well as a js script on the php page include a WYSIWYG editor (I'm using NicEdit)

(The textarea/editor is only on the php page)

This is what my HTML header looks like

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/> 
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

When I submit the form the php page is formatted with the above css and JQM js (even though its not included in my php code). I thought POST only sends information in the form tag? How are the above scripts and css effecting the php page?

On the php page I included the NicEdit scripts to turn the textareas into WYSIWYG editors:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

If I have jquery mobile in the html page the NicEdit scripts in the php page don't work (I just get a plain textarea)
However if I remove all jquery from the html header it works fine! And even if I have the Jquery stuff when I refresh the php page THEN the NicEdit scripts take effect.

- How is the jquery mobile scripts from the html page running on php?
- what possible conflicts could there be to cause the NicEdit scripts to not run?

Comment: The NicEdit runs in javascript, not PHP, because you are using PHP only to include the scripts in the page. The might be some conflict between jQuery Mobile and NicEdit. In which order are they being included in the page? Have you tried changing the order?

Comment: yes the order has been changed in different ways to no avail. however i found that php posts the whole html with it...so that may be the issue.